# Rails w/ HopToad -- Deploying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hoptoad

I have a deployed Rails application that I'd like to use with Hoptoad (an online exception notification service). It comes packaged in a gem that I installed on my deployment server, but I need to run the script/generate hoptoad every time I deploy to configure it because the Hoptoad config files/changes exist only on my production application (and not on my development, so when I deploy, they all get erased).

Is there an easy way to run that script/generate on the production server every time I deploy? I feel like you could do this with Capistrano tasks, but I don't know how to do that.

What do people usually do for this? Sorry if this post is a little hard to understand, I'm not quite sure how to explain the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I am a little confused by this, we use hoptoad with capistrano and we just keep the configuration with the repository and do not have to do a script generate.  Perhaps we are doing it wrong, but I don't see why you would need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can add the Hoptoad configuration file to your source code repository so that it gets deployed as part of the Rails application.
- Alternatively, if you don't want that information within your repository, then upload the config file to your production server (outside of Capistrano's normal `releases` directory structure) and have Capistrano create a symbolic link to it as part of the deployment process. I provided an [answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236375/how-can-i-create-new-symlink-for-ror-application-in-the-public-html-folder) which should give you the idea.